# Hibernate embedded map saving problem

Tags: java, hibernate

I've been having trouble with saving embedded collections. I've come up with this crazy solution because I wanted my lazily loaded models to sort based on fields in resources.

I have three tables:

- assets (id)
- assets_resources (asset_id,resource_id,primary_image)
- resources (id,logical_name)

I have defined the tables with hibernate annotations like so:
Assets.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "assets")
public class Asset implements java.io.Serializable {
@OneToMany
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
name="assets_resources"
, joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="asset_id")
, inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="resource_id")
)
@MapKeyColumn(name="asset_id")
@OrderBy("logical_name")
private Map<AssetResource, Resource> resources;
public Map<AssetResource, Resource > getResources() {return resources;}
public void setResources(Map<AssetResource, Resource> resources) {this.resources = resources;}
}
```

assetResource.java

```
@Embeddable
public class AssetResource {
private Boolean primary_image;
public Boolean getPrimaryImage() {return primary_image;}
public void setPrimaryImage(Boolean primary_image) {this.primary_image = primary_image;}

private Long id;
public Long getId() {return id;}
}
```

resource.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="resources")
public class Resource implements java.io.Serializable {
...
public String logical_name;
public String getLogicalName() {return logical_name;}
public void setLogicalName(String logical_name) { this.logical_name = logical_name;}
}
```

I can iterate though the lazily loaded maps in my controllers but I can't seem to save/update embedded fields. specifically, I can't update the primary_image field.

---

This [link](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/) demonstrates what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to save the attribute value in database. Because i think you won't be able to save the value as u have not mapped it with some column in the database. Try removind Emmbedded and then add the table and column attributes..

Comment: That is what I started with but I was unable to sort directly from the model. I think that the answer lies [in this blog post](http://ozgwei.blogspot.com/2007/12/hibernate-how-to-map-collection-of.html). Specifically where Alex says "it is very important to override the equals() and hashCode()" but unfortunately I've run out of time to research this further and I will be reverting to Standard models and using a DAO method to get the sorted results.